# Multithreading: WaitAll doesn't wait as expected

Tags: c#, multithreading, waithandle

I have a thread that is calling two separate threads to do somework. Whenever any of the jobs is finished a Waithandle.Set(0 is called and at the end of the parent worker thread I wanted to WaitAll for both to be finished, before i continue. But priceA() is still coming up first and then PriceB().

```
new Thread(() =>
                           {
                               new Thread(() =>
                               {
                                   PriceA = _service.GetPriceA();
                                   _waithandle[0].Set();
                               }).Start();

                               new Thread(() =>
                               {
                                   PriceB = _service.GetPriceB();
                                   _waithandle[1].Set();
                               }).Start();

                               WaitHandle.WaitAll(_waithandle);
                           }).Start();
Console.WriteLine("Hello");
```

What am I missing?

**Update:**

```
private EventWaitHandle[] _waithandle;
```

**Ctor:**

```
 _waithandle[0] = new ManualResetEvent(false);
 _waithandle[1] = new ManualResetEvent(false);
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear. The only thing that your WaitAll should do is stopping before the first new Thread() (the one at row 1) finishes. So if you insert a Console.WriteLine("Hello") after the WaitAll, it will print only AFTER both the GetPrice have finished. The order of execution of the GetPrices isn't "fixed". They can be executed as GetPriceA, GetPriceB or GetPriceB, GetPriceA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
new Thread(() =>
                           {
                               new Thread(() =>
                               {
                                   _priceA = _service.GetPriceA();
                                   _waithandle[0].Set();
                               }).Start();

                               new Thread(() =>
                               {
                                   _priceB = _service.GetPriceB();
                                   _waithandle[1].Set();
                               }).Start();

                               WaitHandle.WaitAll(_waithandle);
                               PriceA = _priceA;
                               PriceB = _priceB;
                           }).Start();
```

This did the job for me. Culprit was the INotifyChangedProperty() of the PriceA and PriceB which updated the UI too early making my waitall redundant. In case someone else has a similar issue...

Answer (score 4):

You're creating a *separate thread* to wait... but the code after the statement you've given will continue because you're not waiting in *that* thread. In other words, you're creating three threads:

- Thread X: Creates threads A and B, then waits for them to finish
- Thread A: Gets PriceA and then sets waitHandle[0]
- Thread B: Gets PriceB and then sets waitHandle[1]

But thread X is doing nothing *after* it's waited, so what's the point of waiting within it?

Additionally, it would be a lot simpler to just call `Join` on the extra threads that you've created. In fact, if you only need to wait in the "current" thread, you only need *one* extra thread in the first place:

```
Thread t = new Thread(() => { PriceA = _service.GetPriceA(); });
t.Start();
PriceB = _service.GetPriceB();
t.Join();
// Other code
```

By the time you reach "other code", both PriceA and PriceB will have been set. Of course, this is missing a considerable amount of error handling... but that's easier to add when you've got a simpler starting point than your currently over-complicated code.

Comment: You need to do this in a STA application. Otherwise WaitAll won't let you compile.  But the behaviour you described is exactly what I try to achieve. I have just realized what the problem was....The InotifyChangedProperty of PriceA and PriceB have messed up my intentions.  Now I save them first in a field accordingly and pass them then to the real properties after the WaitAll. That works as expected.

Comment: @Kave: WaitAll will certainly *compile* in a non-STA thread context, but it will blow up at execution time. I'd avoid it if possible though. If you're using .NET 4, the Task Parallel Library makes things even simpler...

Comment: Thanks Jon, I am brushing up my skills for an Interview next week. Its not an real app. :) You are right TPL make things easier, but I have to prepare myself for .NET 3.5. I have posted my answer below as well, in case someone else has overlooked the INotifyChangedproperty() behaviour of the properties as in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Are you resetting correctly the `_waithandle[0]` and `[1]`? For example:

```
_waithandle[0] = new ManualResetEvent(false);
_waithandle[1] = new ManualResetEvent(false);
```